# identify whether a GUI event was fired directly by the user or because of a code assignment in .Net

Tags: .net, events, user-interface

Suppose you are using a control such as *NumericUpDown* which has the *value* property.
and you set the value *numericUpDown1.Value = 10;* then the .net will fire the event *numericaUpDown1ValueChanged(sender, args)*, also the user can directly set the value of this control and the **.Net** will fire the same event with the same sender.

**to be able to identify whether the event was generated by code or by direct user input**,
I would usually wrap my assignment as the following:

```
userDirectlyChangingValue = false;
numericaUpDown1.Value = 10;
userDirectlyChangingValue = true;
```

then within the *numericaUpDown1ValueChanged(sender, args)* event
I would use *userDirectlyChangingValue* to identify the way the event was generated and act accordingly.

my question is, is there a better/direct way in the **.Net** to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is the universally adopted way of doing this.  Unsubscribing the event handler and re-subscribing it afterward is *way* more fugly.